# I cant override the bootstrap in nav bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found a few other posts, but either the bootstrap code is outdated or im not implementing it incorrectly.

Simply put, i want the "bombers hockey" to sit on the left, and the links to be on the right of the nav bar.
HTML -

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

ul li .navbar-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Bombers Hockey</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link navbar-right" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navbar-right" href="sched.html">Schedule</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navbar-right" href="stats.html">Stats</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navbar-right" href="pics.html">Pictures</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="pics/jerseys.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I tried targeting it multiple ways. li, ul, .navbar-right, pull-right, ul li a, etc. nothing moves those links.

Comment: The brand is in the left and the links on the right. Can you elaborate your problem further?

Comment: The links are not on the right on my computer... Hrmm

Comment: So the problem is in the un-collapsed version of the navbar, am I right?

Comment: At full screen, not the burger menu. The nav links are on the left side right next to the Brand. I want the Brand on the left, and the nav links floating to the right. Im trying to bring a bit of balance to my nav bar, but for whatever reason i cant seem to get them to move.

Comment: @KyleSchmelzer Please check my code I think you want like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check in full page snippet code.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {  
  flex-basis: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width:991px){
.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light justify-content-between">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Bombers Hockey</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link navbar-right" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navbar-right" href="sched.html">Schedule</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navbar-right" href="stats.html">Stats</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navbar-right" href="pics.html">Pictures</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="pics/jerseys.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the class **`mr-auto`** to **`ml-auto w-100 justify-content-end`** to the `ul` element and that should align the links to the right. Other than that, there is no change to the HTML markup which you have written.

Hope the below code helps (PS: Didn't notice that you are using Bootstrap 4 beta in my earlier response)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
 }

 img { max-width: 100%; }
</style>

<div class="container">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Bombers Hockey</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
   aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div id="navbarNavDropdown" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
    <li class="nav-item active">
     <a class="nav-link navbar-right" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link navbar-right" href="sched.html">Schedule</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link navbar-right" href="stats.html">Stats</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link navbar-right" href="pics.html">Pictures</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: @KyleSchmelzer In this solution there is an issue in small screen when hamburger is visible.

Comment: @KyleSchmelzer I have updated my code above, and the fix to right align the links. Verified and it works in both desktop and small screens. Actually, your code works, the only is with the class applied to `ul` element. Other than that, I have made no changes to your markup. Hope this helps